# Akka Durable Mailboxes

Tags: akka

What is the implication w.r.t. performance in using Akka durable mailboxes versus the default mailboxes?  Do any benchmarks exist comparing the various backends in terms of time to reconstitute?

Comment: Too many variables bro, you need to bench on your HW and config

Comment: @Viktor Klang.  Ok, fair enough.  Unfortunately, I don't have experience with most of the backends, so I have no real basis for comparison.  I was hoping someone with some experience would share some gems of wisdom that could save me some time / frustration.